# How to write multiple classes in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I have to write a report where I create and implement the Data Type (Set) using java.

I have to write pseudocode for it an include it in my report.

How do I write a class and call it from another pseudocode program.

say I have the Set class:

```
public class Set() {
   public Set() {
      //constructor
      basicMethod();
   }

   public void basicMethod() {
      //do something
   }
}
```

and my driver class:

```
public class Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Set s = new Set();
   }
}
```

How would I write this as pseudocode?

How would instantiate a new object inside of another class?

how would i encompass the class entirely? To define a class in pseudocode would i just say:

```
Set {
    // pseudocode in here
}
```

also, how would I write a constructor in pseudocode?

Comment: the whole point of pseudocode is that it isn't rigorously defined, so you can write what makes intuitively sense. As long as your teacher is able to follow what you mean, your solution should be correct.

Comment: You might even want to skip the definition of the class entirely. If it's clear from context, you can just write `a := a Set of size 10`, and later `a.insert(q)` without ever defining a constructor or a method. At least we were allowed to do that. You should ask your teacher what he expects.